# Remove all facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, removechild, removeall

i have hard time try to kill all facebook features don't like, don't want, don't vereryting.

So i try using gresemonkey to do it, but so far i can't make it work every time i try, fail when i use get document id  lets say "content" works fine buy when i try thinks like "fb-Like" don't do anything . there is what i have so far. i hope us can put me in then right way.

```
//this part  becouse come fb-likes are like class and no have id

var killerface = document.getElementsByClassName("like-box");
for (var i = 0; i < killerface.length; i++) {
    killerface[i].setAttribute("id","like-box");
}
```

this should be remove the child, but it's not...

```
var killerface2 = document.getElementById("like-box");
killerface2.parentNode.removeChild(killerface2);
```

have any ideas?

---

the idea is clean clear remove all pages using greasemonkey from facebook, google plus,any other that follows also some ads and everything dont like you. the idea is not only hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your HTML before last  tag. (Need you have a jquery)

```
<style>
   .deadface { display:none !important; }
</style>


<script>
    $(function() {
    $('.like-box').addClass('deadface');
  });
</script>
```

Or this to completely remove

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    $('div.like-box').remove();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: works great the jquery metod tanks :D

Comment: i try, have less 15 reputation but when i hace ill vote up. :D